# Does anyone know a good snippet collection for APEX, Lightning and SF-specific JS?

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-aura-components, ide

I'm improving our [free IDE CodeFusion](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5SYEEA3) and just added configurable snippet support in the [new version](https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t20000000Hnnh). Internally we are using ACE Editor. Now technically I'm already done and it works like a charm.

With ACE also came a bunch of pre-defined snippets - which are very nice for JavaScript but not perfect for APEX and all Salesforce-special-stuff.

The Snippet-Format is something like ApexMate - it also reminds me of Sublime-Snippets. Just as an example they look like this:

```
snippet for-\n\
    for(var ${1:i} = ${2:Things}.length; ${1:i}--; ) {\n\
        ${0:${2:Things}[${1:i}];}\n\
    }\n\
# for (...) {...}\n\
snippet for\n\
    for(var ${1:i} = 0; $1 < ${2:Things}.length; $1++) {\n\
        ${3:$2[$1]}$0\n\
    }\n\
# for (...) {...} (Improved Native For-Loop)\n\
```

But I don't mind the format - it looks pretty easy to adjust or convert them if necessary.

What I'm more interested in is a snippet-collection which has proven to be good in any environment and has evolved through time and many projects. Sure thing I can write my own - but actually I just started the snippet-business and would have to start form scratch. Now I would be interested if any MavensMate/Sublime/TextMate enthusiast maybe have already something and are in the mood of sharing it with the community?

A short google reseach brought up nothing on the first page. I had also a quick look in Joe Ferraros MavensMate and @superfell ApexMate but either they come without snippets - or I didn't see them.

Anyway one brilliant snippet collection could improve all of our IDEs (at least those supporting them at all). Would you like to share?

Comment: Hello @Uwe Heim. Are you after Javascript snippets only, or Visualforce and Apex as well? I read question title as if everything has to be Javascript related.

Comment: @AdrianLarson As I wrote in the text, for JS I have something (default stuff shipped with ACE Editor). So we have vanilla JS, but no Salesforce-specials. My focus NOW is clearly on APEX first, followed by VF-Markup snippets, followed by Lightning, followed by JS-for-Salesforce-freaks. In exactly that order :-)

Comment: if anyone likes to see it in action, just check it out: https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t20000000Hnnh - feedback welcome

Comment: if Visualforce is on your list then check these snippets: https://github.com/neowit/vim-force.com/blob/master/snippets/visualforce.snippets. This is for vim's UltiSnips, but format looks similar to one in your example, so should not be hard to convert (if necessary).